# MPI Unpacking different values from Packed

Tags: c, mpi

I have a strange issue where the values I am packing into a buffer for an MPI Bcast are different from those that have been unpacked.

I am not sure what this may have resulted from. The first value packed (MTD) is always correct but those afterward are very off.

I require one of these values (dimensions) for dynamic memory allocation, the result of which then causes my program to crash.

If anyone familiar with MPI can cast there eyes over I would be eternally grateful!.

```
    void recv_sharedData(int me, SharedData *d) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: RECEIVING SHARED DATA\n", me);
        int buff_size = sizeof(int) * 4 + sizeof(float);
        char * buffer = malloc(buff_size);
        int position = 0;

        if (MPI_Bcast(
                buffer, 5, MPI_PACKED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) != MPI_SUCCESS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ID %d: Could not receive SharedData", me);
            MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, -1);
        }

        MPI_Unpack(buffer, buff_size, &position, &d->max_tree_depth, 1, 
            MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Unpack(buffer, buff_size, &position, &d->bit_depth, 1, 
            MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Unpack(buffer, buff_size, &position, &d->dimensions, 1, 
            MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Unpack(buffer, buff_size, &position, &d->origin, 1, 
            MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);   
        MPI_Unpack(buffer, buff_size, &position, &d->colour_max, 1, 
            MPI_FLOAT, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 

        fprintf(stderr, "%d: MTD: %d\n", me, d->max_tree_depth);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: BitDepth: %d\n", me, d->bit_depth);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: DIM: %d\n", me, d->dimensions);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: ORIGIN: %d\n", me, d->origin);

....

void bcast_sharedData(SharedData *d) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Broadcasting Shared Data\n");

    int position = 0;
    int buff_size = sizeof(int) * 4 + sizeof(float);
    char * buffer = malloc(buff_size);

    int result = MPI_SUCCESS;
    while(result == MPI_SUCCESS) {
        result = MPI_Pack(&d->max_tree_depth, 1, MPI_INT, buffer, 
                            buff_size, &position, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        result = MPI_Pack(&d->bit_depth, 1, MPI_INT, buffer, buff_size, 
                            &position, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        result = MPI_Pack(&d->dimensions, 1, MPI_INT, buffer, buff_size, 
                            &position, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
        result = MPI_Pack(&d->origin, 1, MPI_INT, buffer, buff_size, 
                            &position, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        result = MPI_Pack(&d->colour_max, 1, MPI_FLOAT, buffer, 
                            buff_size, &position, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        break;
    }

    if (result != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, 
                "ID 0: Could not Pack Shared Data for Broadcasting");
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, -1);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "%d: MTD: %d\n", 0, d->max_tree_depth);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: BitDepth: %d\n", 0, d->bit_depth);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: DIM: %d\n", 0, d->dimensions);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: ORIGIN: %d\n", 0, d->origin);
```

The related values to the above are output below. The root values (0:) are what are being packed:

```
Broadcasting Shared Data
0: MTD: 2
0: BitDepth: 24
0: DIM: 19
0: ORIGIN: 9
3: MTD: 2
3: BitDepth: 32536
3: DIM: 11816240
3: ORIGIN: 0
3: Done Recieving SharedData
1: MTD: 2
1: BitDepth: 32536
1: DIM: 30698800
1: ORIGIN: 0
1: Done Recieving SharedData
1: ALLOCATING KERNEL
2: MTD: 2
2: BitDepth: 32536
2: DIM: 27622704
2: ORIGIN: 0
2: Done Recieving SharedData
```

Comment: You are only communicating the first 5 bytes of the packing unit. You should use the value of `position` after the last `MPI_Pack` call as the number of `MPI_PACKED` elements to send. On the receiver side, use a large enough buffer. Also, why not define a structure datatype (see `MPI_Type_create_struct`) and use it instead of packing/unpacking?

Comment: Requirement is to use unpack. Would you be able to to post an example of what you are referring to?